# how to solve this? Error is showing in the word 'byte' while trying to convert unit to byte-- "byte(uint8(departureBytes[i]) + 1)"

Tags: solidity, blockchain

```
function encryptTicketDetails(string memory _departureTime, string memory _arrivalTime, string memory _fromDestination, string memory _toDestination) private pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory departureBytes = bytes(_departureTime);
    bytes memory arrivalBytes = bytes(_arrivalTime);
    bytes memory fromBytes = bytes(_fromDestination);
    bytes memory toBytes = bytes(_toDestination);
    
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < departureBytes.length; i++) {
        departureBytes[i] = byte(uint8(departureBytes[i]) + 1);
    }
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < arrivalBytes.length; i++) {
        arrivalBytes[i] = byte(uint8(arrivalBytes[i]) + 1);
    }
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < fromBytes.length; i++) {
        fromBytes[i] = byte(uint8(fromBytes[i]) + 1);
    }
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < toBytes.length; i++) {
        toBytes[i] = byte(uint8(toBytes[i]) + 1);
    }
    
    return string(departureBytes) 
        .concat("_")
        .concat(string(arrivalBytes))
        .concat("_")
        .concat(string(fromBytes))
        .concat("_")
        .concat(string(toBytes));
}
```

Comment: Change byte to bytes.